# Python equivalent to Ogmios?

Tags: python, syncing, library

Has somebody written a library equivalent to Ogmios, that has the same functionalities, including a chain sync protocol, but entirely written in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put this library together as I needed to access Ogmios from a Python application. It is still a work in progress, but it is working.

https://pypi.org/project/pyogmios/

Comment: I accepted your answer and gave a look at the repo. Very impressive that you built this. Will there be more documentation available over time? For example, how to store UTxO/asset data in SQL(ite) databases/dealing with chain rollbacks?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I am currently rewriting it to work with the latest version of Ogmios (v6.0.*). I can include some example code on handling the cases you mentioned, but the implementation details may differ as I am using MongoDB for the database.

Answer (score 3):

https://pypi.org/project/pycardano/

I think this is as close as it gets with Python so far...